# how to output results of STCentroid to STContains function?

Tags: sql-server-2008, gis, geospatial, esri

I'm currently using

```
X_Coord =CASE WHEN shape.STDimension() = 2 THEN shape.STCentroid().STX ELSE shape.STEnvelope().STCentroid().STX END, 
Y_Coord =CASE WHEN shape.STDimension() = 2 THEN shape.STCentroid().STY ELSE shape.STEnvelope().STCentroid().STY END,
```

to populate an X and Y column in a polygon geometry table. However, I also would like to populate a location table, e.g., what Topographic Map boundary the centroid of the polygon occurs within.

This

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN atbi.dbo.TLU_TOPO_BOUNDS  AS b  
ON b.Shape.STContains(a.Shape) = 1
```

works fine on point geometry, but fails on polygons for 2 reasons: it often has difficulty determining what polygon another is "within", and for reason # 1, reason # 2 is a fatal error.

So how could I achieve the same results, using the polygon centroid to determine which corresponding polygon,from another polygon geometry table, that the inserted polygon centroid lies within?

Full code of what I'm doing here:

```
ALTER TRIGGER   [dbo].[GRSM_WETLAND_POLY_GIS_Location_ID]
ON  [dbo].[GRSM_WETLANDS_POLY]
INSTEAD OF INSERT   
AS   
BEGIN   
  SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  INSERT dbo.GRSM_WETLANDs_POLY(
  OBJECTID, MapMethod, HError, MapSource, SourceDate, 
  EditDate, Notes, Meta_MID, X_Coord, Y_Coord, Coord_Units, 
  Coord_System, UTM_Zone, Accuracy_Notes, Unit_Code, Loc_Name, 
  Loc_Notes, Datum, Watershed, StreamName, NHDReachCode, Trail, 
  Road, Elevation, LAT, LON, Year_, County, ST, IsExtant, IsSenstive, 
  LocationDescription, LocationDirections, PlaceName, FCSubtype, 
  Landform, Area_Acres, Area_Hectares, DataFile, DataDictionary, 
  Max_PDOP, Max_HDOP, Corr_Type, Rcvr_Type,  SHAPE, QuadName
  )

  SELECT 
  a.OBJECTID, a.MapMethod, a.HError, a.MapSource, a.SourceDate, 
  a.EditDate, a.Notes, a.Meta_MID, a.X_Coord, a.Y_Coord, a.Coord_Units, 
  a.Coord_System, a.UTM_Zone, a.Accuracy_Notes, a.Unit_Code, a.Loc_Name, 
  a.Loc_Notes, a.Datum, a.Watershed, a.StreamName, a.NHDReachCode, a.Trail, 
  a.Road, a.Elevation, a.LAT, a.LON, a.Year_, a.County, a.ST, a.IsExtant, a.IsSenstive, 
  a.LocationDescription, a.LocationDirections, a.PlaceName, a.FCSubtype, 
  a.Landform, a.Area_Acres, a.Area_Hectares, a.DataFile, a.DataDictionary, 
  a.Max_PDOP, a.Max_HDOP, a.Corr_Type, a.Rcvr_Type, a.SHAPE, a.QuadName
  From
  (  
    SELECT  
OBJECTID, MapMethod, HError, MapSource, SourceDate, 
EditDate, Notes, Meta_MID, 
X_Coord =CASE WHEN shape.STDimension() = 2 THEN shape.STCentroid().STX ELSE shape.STEnvelope().STCentroid().STX END, 
Y_Coord =CASE WHEN shape.STDimension() = 2 THEN shape.STCentroid().STY ELSE shape.STEnvelope().STCentroid().STY END, 
Coord_Units, 
Coord_System, UTM_Zone, Accuracy_Notes, Unit_Code, Loc_Name, 
Loc_Notes, Datum, Watershed, StreamName, NHDReachCode, Trail, 
Road, Elevation, LAT, LON, Year_, County, ST, IsExtant, IsSenstive, 
LocationDescription, LocationDirections, PlaceName, FCSubtype, 
Landform, Area_Acres, Area_Hectares, DataFile, DataDictionary, 
Max_PDOP, Max_HDOP, Corr_Type, Rcvr_Type, SHAPE,QuadName
     FROM inserted  
  ) AS a 
  --Not working:
  ---spatial query, what topo quad is this point in? 
 --LEFT OUTER JOIN atbi.dbo.TLU_TOPO_BOUNDS  AS b  
--ON b.Shape.STContains(a.Shape) = 1 ;
end

GO
```

If you have to ask about the rest of the trigger, this is sitting on top of the ESRI SDE stack, so what should be a simple trigger gets complex when I have to deal with the mandatory objectid, but everything else is working, just need to figure out the centroid STwithin. Thanks!

Comment: You could extract the centroid of a.Shape on run the join on that eg ON b.Shape.STContains(a.Shape.STCentroid()) = 1